# Abbreviation Classification using machine learning

Tags: machine-learning

I would like to classify abbreviations using machine learning. For example:
I have watermel. and I ask for user what is watermel.(my application context is about food). Then He classify as watermelon.
In other time, If Other user insert waterme. Is It exist a way to infer that waterme is the same as watermelon using machine learning techniques?

Comment: You could use Machine Learning in general to solve this problem, but I feel your problem will have a more elegant solution in NLP. Please check that out first. Things like semantic analysis etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into this package for Python:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Distance/

You can use this to generate a numeric value representing the similarity between word.

Here is a similar post that should help:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/123060/clustering-a-long-list-of-strings-words-into-similarity-groups

Additionally, a level up in complexity would be to use t-SNE on an array generated using word2vec (this is word embedding).  Examples and resources for this are:
https://www.codeproject.com/tips/788739/visualization-of-high-dimensional-data-using-t-sne
http://sebastianruder.com/word-embeddings-1/

Comment: Thaks for these references. I'll learn study about it.

Answer (score 0):

Natural Language Processing/Text Mining may help you to find out a possible solution to your problem. Because, in your case, it is inevitable to handle them with lexical parsers and analysers.

Hope this may helps!!

Comment: Ty Man I'll search about NLP